# What do I do to make a python script that can run from any directory: the script file doesn’t have to be in the same directory as the .csv files?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently, I have created a code that makes graphs from data in .csv files.  However, I can only run the code if that code is present in the folder with the csv files.  How can I make the the script file so that it doesn't have to be in the same directory as the .csv files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to include a fixed CSV file with your code, store an absolute path based on the script path:

```
HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

csv_filename = open(os.path.join(HERE, 'somefile.csv')
```

`__file__` is the filename of the current module or script, `os.path.dirname(__file__)` is the directory the module resides in. For scripts, `__file__` can be a relative pathname, so we use `os.path.abspath()` to turn that into an absolute path.

This means you can run your script from anywhere.

If you meant to make your script work with *arbitrary* CSV input files, use command line options:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('CSV importer')
    parser.add_argument('csvfile', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
                        default='somedefaultfilename.csv')
    options = parser.parse_args()
    import_function(options.csvfile)
```

where `csvfile` will be an open file object, so your `import_function()` can just do:

```
def import_function(csvfile):
    with csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            # etc.
```

Comment: This is a good default, but for extra flexibility you should include (with `optparse` or your own command-line option parser) the ability to specify the target path containing your .csv files, overriding that default.

Comment: what if I have a directory of csv files and do not want to just look over "somefile.csv"?  how do you join two directories?

Comment: @user2614937: That is a new subject; given a path, `os.listdir()` will list all filenames in that directory. If you struggle with that, make sure to read the Python documentation and if you are still stuck, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan on moving around the csv files too much, the best answer is to hard code the **absolute** path to the csv folder into the script.

```
import os

csvdir = "/path/to/csv/dir"
csvfpath = os.path.join(csvdir, "myfile.csv")
csvfile = open(csvfpath)
```

You can also use a command line parser like `argparse` to let the user easily change the path to the csv files.

Using Martijn Pieters's solution will work *only* if you are going to be moving the folder containing both the script and csv files around. However in that case, you may as well just use relative paths to the csv files.